# Show and hide not hiding elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys so i am building a simple menu only and i have 8 sections on it, for some reason those it was all working fine from section 1-3 but when i got past section 4, it stats to show everything. So from 1-3 it was working fine , when i hide and show it works amazing, when i added in anther section to make it 4 , it stops working completely and shows everything.

Fiddle link: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/40118/)

So you can see the hide and show secltion is not working at all and i have no idea why:

Javascript:

```
$("li a[id]").click(function() {
  $(".targetDiv").hide().filter("." + this.id ).show();
})
```

Thanks for the help

Edit: So you can see at the start it shows everything but when you click on a button it goes back to normal and it works fine, so again i have no idea why its doing this

Comment: Add relevant code in OP not in an external link use `<>` for demo

Comment: Please try to scale demos down to minimal representations of problem. There is so much html in your demo it's time consuming to figure out what shoud or shouldn't be shown

Comment: Sorry i will do that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to this?

```js
$(".targetDiv:not(.menu1)").hide();
$("li a[id]").click(function() {
  $(".targetDiv").hide().filter("." + this.id ).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="categories">
        <ul class="cat">
          <li>
            <ol class="type">
              <li><a href="#" class="active" id="menu1">Ät 2 betala för 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"  id="menu2">À LA CARTE - EJ 2 FÖR 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"  id="menu3">Lunchen</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"  id="menu4">SÖNDAGSMIDDAG</a></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu1">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">FÖRDRINK</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Dry martini / Vodka Martini </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 118 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Gin, torr vermouth, oliv/vodka, torr vermouth, oliv</div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> White lady </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 118 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Gin, cointreau, äggvita, citronjuice, cocktailbär (skakas) </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Rusty nail </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 118 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Scotch whisky, drambuie, is. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Manhattan  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 118 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Kanadensisk whisky, röd och vit Vermouth, angostura bitter, cocktailbär </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Bloody Mary  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 118 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Original </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Bryggans fördrink </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 118 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Mynta, gin, florsocker, äggvita, citronsaft, blåbärslikör (skakas) </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Eget önskemål  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> Pris beror på val </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Vi blandar gärna vad ni önskar som fördrink </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu1">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">FÖRRÄTT</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Hembakat ostgratinerad vitlöksbröd  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 76 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Med aioli. </div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Triss di bruschette  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 148 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Tre olika smaker av fyllning på grillat lantbröd. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Anti pasto tallrik  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 169 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Parmaskinka, bresaola, salami, cinghiale, oliver, parmesanost, soltorkade tomater, kronärtskocka, bruschetta. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Buffallo wings   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> hot’n sweet glaserade buffallo wings med blue cheese dressing och bladselleri.</div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Toast skagen   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Lyxig räk och kräftröra. serveras på grillat hembakat bröd och citrusdressad roccula. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Fagottino di bresaola  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Gorgonzolafyllda bresaola på en bädd av ruccola, balsamico, hyvlad parmesan, rostat hembakat bröd. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu1">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">VARMRÄTTER</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Pepparstek 200gr.  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 399 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Oxfilé, pepparsås, wokade färska grönsaker, valfritt tillbehör.</div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Grillad entrecôte   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 329 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Serveras med örtsmör, rödvinsås, wokade färska grönsaker, valfritt tillbehör. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Filetto d’agnello alla griglia   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 329 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Grillad lammytterfilé med rosmarin, rödvinsås, valfritt tillbehör. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Citron & timjanmarinerad ekologisk kycklingfilé   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 289 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Krämig örtsås och balsamico, wokade färska grönsaker, valfritt tillbehör. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Stekt norsk fjodlax   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 298 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> På en bädd av ljumma primörer, hovmästarsås och fransk potatissallad. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Tillbehör  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Pommes frites, klyftpotatis, potatisgratäng, ungsrostade rotfrukter, mixad sallad med rhode island dressing eller tomat & löksallad med basilikaolja. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Extra tillbehör   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 25 - 15 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Utöver som ingår i rätten - Såser </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu1">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">Desserter</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Passionsfrukts pannacotta.   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Hemlagad. serveras med skogsbärssås och färska bär. </div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Créme brulée   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Vaniljkräm med knäckigt täcke av råsocker. serveras med färska bär och sorbét </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Chokladvariation   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 169 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Chokladbakverk, cognacschokladmousse, saffranstryffel, sorbét. serveras med färska bär. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Hallon semifreddo    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Hemlagad semifreddo smaksatt med hallon och vanilj. serveras med säsongens bär, toppad med chokladbitar.</div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Tiramisu al limone    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Klassisk hemlagad italiensk tiramisu. smaksatt med citronsmak. serveras med färska bär. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Ost tallrik    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 199 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Serveras med talleggio, brieost, parmesan, roquefortost, pecorino, gorgonzola, färska päron, rostat bröd, fikonmarmelad, cherrymarmelad. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row targetDiv menu2">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">Le nostre paste – alla våra pasta</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Papardelle al filetto e tartufo     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 149 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Färsk pasta med oxfilé, tryffelolja, karl johan svamp, toppas med ruccola och parmesan. </div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Tagliatelle al pollo e marsala    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 145 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Färsk pasta med ekologisk kyckling, grädde, champinjoner, paprikamix, lök, marsala, ruccola och parmesan.</div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Köksmästarens papardelle del mare     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 178 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Färsk papardelle med tigerräkor, basilika, tryffel, valnötter, mascarpone, grädde, toppas med en färsk hel havskräfta och ruccola.</div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Linguine allo scoglio     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 178 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Platta spaghetti med havskräfta, tigerräkor, blåmusslor, lax, vitlök, tomatsås, basilika, toppas med ruccola.</div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Risotto con scampi e gambero    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 178 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Risotto med scampi, räkor, färsk sparris, lime, toppas med havskräfta och ruccola.</div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Spaghetti alla carbonara     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Spaghetti, bacon, äggula, grädde, svartpeppar och parmesan, toppas med ruccola.</div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Spaghetti alla bolognese     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Spaghetti med nötköttfärssås. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Lasagnette al forno     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Ugnsgratinerad färsk bred papardelle med köttfärssås, bechamelsås, mozzarellaost, parmesan.</div>
          </div>
             <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Raviolacci vegetariani     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Stora ravioli fyllda med ricottaost och spenat. med färska grönsaker, basilika, tomatsås och mozzarellaost toppas med ruccola.
 </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">Alltid på bryggeriet – köttE</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Plankstek    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 229 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Oxfilé, fläskfilé, bearnaisesås, bacon lindad sparris, tomat, rödvinsås & duchesse potatis. </div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Grillad oxfilé    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 229 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Serveras på igen bädd av säsongens ljumma primörer och äppelportvinsås, toppas med krispig parma flarn/skivor. </div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Grilad oxfilé med kantarellsås     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 229 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">I amaronesås och säsongens primörer, valfritt tillbehör. </div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Filé mignon    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Fläskfilé, bearnaisesås, rödvinsås, pommes frites. </div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Clubsandwich    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 169 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Oxfilé medaljonger på grillat bröd, med sallad, tomat, roccula, dijonsenapsmajonnäs, knaperstekt bacon, hyvlad parmesan och pommes frites.</div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Ceasarsallad    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 148 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Med grillad ekologisk kyckling. romansallad, krutonger, parmesan, bacon & ceasardressing.</div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Räkmacka xl    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 169 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Grillat bröd med sallad, handskalade räkor, gurka, tomater, ägg, citron, dill och majonnäs. </div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Bryggeriets fiskgratäng på planka     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 189 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Med två sorters fisk, vitvinsås, duchessepotatis, räkor. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row targetDiv menu2">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">ÄKTA HAMBURGARE</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Bacon & cheddar.   </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 149 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Hamburgare på högrev, nybakat briochebröd, syltad rödlök, cowslaw, saltgurka, bryggeriets hamburgerdressing, sallad, tomat, cheddarost och bacon. serveras med pommes. </div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Burger & wings    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 169 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Hamburgare på högrev, nybakat briochebröd, syltad rödlök, cowslaw, saltgurka, bryggeriets hamburgerdressing, sallad, tomat, friterade lökringar. hot’n sweet glaserade buffalo wings, blue cheese dressing. serveras med pommes. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">Barnmeny (9år): </h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Mini hamburgare tallrik     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 89 </div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Spaghetti med köttfärssås    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 79 </div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Grillad korv med pommes     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 79 </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row targetDiv menu2">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">Italienska pizzor</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Capricciosa  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Tomat, mozzarellaost, skinka, champinjoner. </div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Pescatora    </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 149 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Tomat, mozzarellaost, räkor, musslor, lax, bläckfisk, persilja och vitlök, toppas med ruccola. </div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Pollo é pesto     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 144 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Tomat, mozzarellaost, champinjoner, kyckling, pesto. </div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Vegetariana     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 139 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Tomat, mozzarellaost, oliver, champinjoner, grillade zucchini och aubergine, toppas med cocktailtomater och ruccola.  </div>
          </div>
              <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Quattro stagioni     </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 149 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Tomat, mozzarellaost, skinka, champinjoner, handskalade färska räkor, kronärtskocka.</div>
          </div>
     <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Della valtellina  </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 149 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Tomat, mozzarellaost, gorgonzolaost, toppas med lufttorkad oxfilé, ruccola och cocktailtomater.</div>
          </div>
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Parma </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> 159 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">Tomat, mozzarellaost, parmaskinka, ruccola, cocktailtomater, hyvlad parmesanost. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
   <div class="lunchtitle targetDiv menu3">
   <h4> Lunchen serveras mellan kl - 11.00 och 14.30</h4>
   <p>
   Lunch inklusive salladsbuffé, måltidsdryck, bröd, smör, kaffe o kaka <b>:99 kr</b>.
<br>Enbart salladsbuffé <b>85kr</b>.
<br>Lunchkuponger <b>890kr för 10st</b>.
   </p>
   </div>
 
     <div class="row targetDiv menu3">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">MÅNDAG</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">

            <div class="menu-item-description">Grillad Ryggbiff serveras med Palsternacksmos, Färskriven Pepparrot, Rå äggula samt Rödvinssås.
Stekt Lax serveras med smörslungad Dill, Ärtpesto och Gräslökspotatis.
Pasta med Köttfärssås, Gorgonzola, Champinjoner och Piri piri, toppad med Ruccola. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">TISDAG</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-description">Stekt Fläsk serveras med Raggmunk och Lingon alt. Löksås och Kokt Potatis.
Pocherad Sejfilé serveras med Vitvinssås, Räkor, Broccoli samt Kokt Potatis och Citron.
Pasta med Oxfilé, Pepparsås, Champinjoner, Paprika och Purjolök, toppad med Ruccola och Parmesan.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row targetDiv menu3">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">ONSDAG</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">

            <div class="menu-item-description">Klassisk Wallenbergare serveras med Gräddsås, Gröna ärtor, Lingon samt Potatismos.
Ugnsbakad Torskfilé med soltorkade Tomater, knaperstekt Bacon, Dillsås och Ugnsbakad Potatis.
Gratinerad Köttfylld Tortellini med Tomat- och Basilikasås, Skinka, Zucchini och Mozzarella, toppad m Ruccola. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">TORSDAG</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-description">Ärtsoppa på klassiskt vis med Korv och rimmad Bog samt Pannkakor, Sylt och Grädde.
Havets Wallenbergare serveras Sötpotatispuré, Gröna Ärtor, Pepparrot samt Persikamajonnäs.
Pasta med Kyckling, Paprika, Champinjoner, Grädde och Vitlök, toppad med Ruccola och Parmesan.
Torsdagsmys, Pannkakor ingår till samtliga rätter.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="row targetDiv menu3">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">FREDAG</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-description">Schnitzel Sorrentina med Mozzarella, Färska Tomater, Basilika samt Rödvinssås och Stekt Potatis.
Klassisk Fish and Chips med Remouladsås, Citron och Dill.
Pasta med Bacon, Tryffelkräm, Lök, Grädde och Purjolök, toppad med Parmesan.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
      <div class="row targetDiv menu4">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> 2 rätters middag </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price">  199 </div>
          </div>
      </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
         <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> 3 rätters middag </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price">  229 </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
  </div>
```

Comment: This works like a charm actually, but it dosen;t show the first menu but that should be fine

Comment: @RonTheOld Oh you want the first menu to be shown by default?

Comment: Ye that would be fantastic if you can

Comment: @RonTheOld Updated again, to consider the entire menu1. Check it out.

Comment: Ah what did u do? I cant see it

Comment: Ah i see it now :0 perfect, thank you again so much for ur help xxx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160978/discussion-between-highdef-and-rontheold).

Comment: @RonTheOld No problem :)